# Solving for linear combination of variables

Tags: equation-solving, replacement, variable

I have a set of constraints on nine variables,

```
{a - b/3 - c/3 == x1, 
-(d/3) + e - f/3 == x2,
-(g/3) - h/3 + i == x3, 
a d - (b d)/3 - (c d)/3 - (a e)/3 + b e - (c e)/3 - (a f)/3 - (b f)/3 + c f == x4, 
a g - (b g)/3 - (c g)/3 - (a h)/3 + b h - (c h)/3 - (a i)/3 - (b i)/3 + c i == x5, 
d g - (e g)/3 - (f g)/3 - (d h)/3 + e h - (f h)/3 - (d i)/3 - (e i)/ 3 + f i == x6, 
a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 2/3 (a b + a c + b c) == 1, 
d^2 + e^2 + f^2 - 2/3 (d e + d f + e f) == 1, 
g^2 + h^2 + i^2 - 2/3 (g h + g i + h i) == 1}
```

Given this I need to solve for linear combinations of the variables. For example, I need to find `-a/3+b-c/3` in terms of `x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6`.

`Solve` and `Reduce` do not recognize such combinations as variables, hence I cannot apply that directly. Solving for the variables itself takes too long to run or gives an empty set.

These are all the combinations that I have to solve for,

```
-a/3 + b - c/3
-a/3 - b/3 + c
d - e/3 - f/3
-d/3 - e/3 + f
g - h/3 - i/3
-g/3 + h - i/3
```

Comment: This might just not be tractable. I'll let what I'm trying run for a while and see if it gives a result, hangs, or takes down my machine.

Comment: would post your code as an answer. I dont even know how to frame this in mathematica

Comment: There are four equations `{a - b/3 - c/3 == x1, 
 a d - (b d)/3 - (c d)/3 - (a e)/3 + 
   b e - (c e)/3 - (a f)/3 - (b f)/3 + c f == x4, 
 a g - (b g)/3 - (c g)/3 - (a h)/3 + 
   b h - (c h)/3 - (a i)/3 - (b i)/3 + c i == x5, 
 a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 2/3 (a b + a c + b c) == 1}` which include `{a,b,c}`. In the general case this is impossible.

Comment: I dont understand why its impossible in the general case? @user64494

Comment: Are there any constraints on the solutions, for instance, all `Real` or all `Integer`?  Also, why is it important to solve for the specific linear combinations instead of solving for the nine unknowns and then forming the linear combinations?  Of course, this approach is computationally intensive too.

Comment: Its not important to solve for linear combinations instead of the variables itself. Its just that I dont care for the individual values of the variables. The variables are all real numbers

Comment: @Dotman: See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_polynomial_equations) for info.

Answer (score 6):

Incomplete answer but maybe a start.

```
eqns = {a - b/3 - c/3 == x1, -(d/3) + e - f/3 == 
    x2, -(g/3) - h/3 + i == x3, 
   a d - (b d)/3 - (c d)/3 - (a e)/3 + 
     b e - (c e)/3 - (a f)/3 - (b f)/3 + c f == x4, 
   a g - (b g)/3 - (c g)/3 - (a h)/3 + 
     b h - (c h)/3 - (a i)/3 - (b i)/3 + c i == x5, 
   d g - (e g)/3 - (f g)/3 - (d h)/3 + 
     e h - (f h)/3 - (d i)/3 - (e i)/3 + f i == x6, 
   a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 2/3 (a b + a c + b c) == 1, 
   d^2 + e^2 + f^2 - 2/3 (d e + d f + e f) == 1, 
   g^2 + h^2 + i^2 - 2/3 (g h + g i + h i) == 1};
```

Define a new equation for the expression we want to solve for.

```
neweqn = expr == -a/3 + b - c/3;
```

We want to retain certain variables, and eliminate the rest.

```
vars = {expr, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6};
elims = Complement[Variables[polys], vars];
```

Turn the equations into polynomials (so we solve for the zeros).

```
polys = Apply[Subtract, Append[eqns, neweqn], {1}];
```

The idea now is to find a Groebner basis. But this might not be tractable (runs for hours at a minimum).

```
gb = GroebnerBasis[polys, vars, elims, 
   MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder];
```

Possibly a variation on this will be better behaved.